# list records which do not meet a certain criteria in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got 3 tables please see the below. Currently, a car has a unique tag assigned to them. I have employees with multiple roles. There are only 3 roles. 1 = Surveyor, 2 = Admin or 3 = Engineer.

A car can be assigned to more than one employee. One car can have a surveyor, admin and engineer using it. But I would like to have a list of all car tags that do not have a surveyor.

| CarTags |
| --- |
| tag |
| company_name |
| account_id |

| Employees |
| --- |
| id |
| name |
| email |
| account_id |
| role_id |

| Roles |
| --- |
| employee_id |
| role_name |
| role_id |

For the column role_id in the Roles table, there can be 3 options. 1 = Surveyor, 2 = Admin or 3 = Engineer

The below Oracle SQL query returns me a list of all car tags, company names, employee id, employee names, employee emails and role id's but how can I get a list of all car tags which do not have a surveyor assigned to it?

```
SELECT
    cartags.tag                  AS "TAG Name",
    cartags.company_name         AS "Company Name",
    Employees.id                 AS "Employee ID",
    Employees.name               AS "Employee Name",
    Employees.email              AS "Email Address",
    Roles.id                     AS "Role ID"
FROM
    Employees INNER JOIN cartags ON cartags.account_id = Employees.acount_id
    INNER JOIN Roles ON roles.employee_id = Employees.id
```

Comment: can you please provide data with your tables in textform a create table would also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used CTE (common table expression) to get a list of account_id with a Surveyor in it.  Then on your query, I will use that cte table to exclude accounts_ids in the where condition.

```
WITH Excluded as (
SELECT 
    Employees.account_id
FROM 
    Employees
    INNER JOIN Roles  ON Roles.employee_id = Employees.id
WHERE 
    Roles.role_id = 1
)
SELECT
    cartags.tag                  AS "TAG Name",
    cartags.company_name         AS "Company Name",
    Employees.id                 AS "Employee ID",
    Employees.name               AS "Employee Name",
    Employees.email              AS "Email Address" 
FROM
    Employees 
    INNER JOIN CarTags ON CarTags.account_id = Employees.account_id
    INNER JOIN Roles ON Roles.employee_id = Employees.id
    INNER JOIN Excluded ON Excluded.account_id <> Employees.account_id

sample output:  
AG Name Company Name    Employee ID Employee Name   Email Address
tag2    company2        4           Admin adam  Admina2dam@adm.com
tag2    company2        5           Engr adam   Engr2adam@adm.com
tag3    company3        6           Admin adam  Admin3adam@adm.com
```

[See sample data here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6956bd/1)